# Searching oil well SVG-symbols

Tags: qgis, svg

I’m looking for a set of SVG oil well symbols for QGIS.

Black Bart data: http:// blackbartdata . com / QGIS_Petro_SVG_Symbols

Just directs me to a spam page.

Any other alternatives?

This is a picture of the symbols I ma searching for:[image]

Comment: Have you seen these resources [Icons | Petroleum Icons](https://icons8.com/icons/set/petroleum), [Flaticon](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/petroleum), [More icons & symbols for QGIS](https://anitagraser.com/2016/10/23/more-icons-symbols-for-qgis/)?

Comment: Thank you for these links. Unfortunately they are not the right materials. I am searchng for the specialised oil and gas well symbols used by the operators. This is the link to the ESRI version. https://esri-styles.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=c46a93768f064a50814174c48bec10fe

Answer (score 2):

Everything that I have found so far, I hope will come in handy ...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LRkdnI1YK_-4x0u-RfGex36o1yKiXfrl/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

I found this file ESRI Oil, Gas & Water Regular font, just download install it like a font.  To use it select this font name then type in the symbol you want to use refer to character map, for example type W for dry hole symbol.

[image]
https://media.fontsgeek.com/generated/e/s/esri-oil-gas-water-regular-charmap.png

Hope it help.